# Syntax error while compiling arrays in java

Tags: java

This is a part of code i was working on .. but the compiler showed an error on  line 1. (`Syntax error on token";", , expected`). Why is that error coming??

```
public class variable 
{

           int[] nums;
           nums= new int[7];
}
```

Comment: You're trying to use an assignment statement outside a method/constructor. Either just use `int[] nums = new int[7];` or put the assignment in a constructor.

Comment: no methods in class `variable`?

Comment: In Java instructions can be only in methods. Not directly in class body.

Comment: But you can use initilizers like: `int[] num = new int[7];`

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the Array in same line as the declaration

```
public class variable 
{

           int[] nums = new int[7];
}
```

or you have to initialize it in a method or constructor:

```
 public class variable 
{

   int[] nums;
   public variable(){

           nums= new int[7];
   }
}
```

Hint: read about Java naming conventions. Class names should start with uppercase character.

Answer (score 1):

You should use assignment inside a `method` or a `constructor`.  Or you can instantiate it class level but you have to initialize it same line with declaration.

Eg: Class level instantiation.

```
public class Variable {
    int[] nums = new int[7];
}
```

Use inside a method.

```
public class Variable {
    int[] nums;
    public void method(){            
        nums = new int[7];
    }
}
```